Potential + とこ + verb?
The character is stuck with a flat tire and needs to go to  a place. He's unsure of what should he and if he can make in time and says
行けるとこ行くか?
What is the potential here?

Isn't it 行けるとこまで行くか?

I just checked again and no. Unless it's omitted

Since @naruto asked if he really said 行けるとこまで行くか and the answer was no, it then must be the colloquial version of 行けるところに行くか.

とこ is a colloquial variant of ところ: ☞ What's the meaning of とこに?
に is sometimes omitted in speech when it is obvious, as well as が and を: ☞ 会話では助詞を省略することができるかできないか、くわしく説明してもらいたいです。

So it is simple:

行けるとこ行くか？
行けるところに行くか？
Should (we?) go (some)where (we?) can go?


Just to clarify, this means "車なしで行けるところに代わりに行くか" or "Should we go somewhere (else) we can go (without the car)?", assuming changing the destination is an option?

Yes, that's what I assume.
